# How do you enforce unique across 2 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-design

**Requirements**:

1. Every employee has a unique ID. (EPID)
2. A employee can only be either one of below,

   - FT - Full Time
   - PT - Part Time
3. Any employee can never be both FT and PT.
4. FT & PT have lots of different fields to capture.

**Implementation**:

```
Create Table EmpFT( EPID int primary key,  F1, F2, etc)
Create Table EmpPT( EPID int primary key,  P1, P2, etc)
--This does not prevent same EPID on both EmpFT and EmpPT.
```

**How do you implement No. 3 in database?**

I am using SQL Server 2012 standard edition.

Comment: You should have only one table: `Create Table EmpFT( EPID int primary key, IsPTorFT, Col1, Col2, etc)`

Comment: @Lamak, thought of it. but FT and PT have lots of difference, put them in one table, end up with lots of blank fields.

Comment: @Sam558 Then it's a 3 table solution.  Fields that are common to all employees go in the employee table (EPID, name, SSN, hiredate, whatever) and things that are distinct to Part time or Full time employees go into their own, respective tables that are linked to the main employee table by foreign key.  employee_pt(EPID, <part-time fields>)  and employee_ft(EPID, <full-time fields>)

Comment: @Greenspark, a bad application can still create same EPID in all 3 tables.

Comment: It seems you can use an indexed view.  I haven't had much opportunity to work with these, but here's a [link](http://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/) that could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp(EPID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    t CHAR(2) NOT NULL, UNIQUE (EPID,t));

CREATE TABLE EmpFT(EPID INT PRIMARY KEY, ... other columns
    t CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (t = 'FT'),
    FOREIGN KEY (EPID,t) REFERENCES Emp (EPID,t));

CREATE TABLE EmpPT(EPID INT PRIMARY KEY, ... other columns
    t CHAR(2) NOT NULL CHECK (t = 'PT'),
    FOREIGN KEY (EPID,t) REFERENCES Emp (EPID,t));
```

Comment: Good answer. I would just add a check constraint on Emp.t (t in ('FT', 'PT')) for completeness.

Comment: when the uniqueness grows to more than 2 tables, this answer scales elegantly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add check constraints. Something like this for both tables

```
ALTER TABLE EmpFT
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_EmpFT_EPID CHECK (dbo.CHECK_EmpPT(EPID)= 0)
ALTER TABLE EmpPT
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_EmpPT_EPID CHECK (dbo.CHECK_EmpFT(EPID)= 0)
```

And the functions like so:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_EmpFT(@EPID int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret int;   
SELECT @ret = count(*) FROM EmpFT WHERE @EPID = EmpFT.EPID
RETURN @ret;
END
GO


CREATE FUNCTION CHECK_EmpPT(@EPID int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret int;   
SELECT @ret = count(*) FROM EmpPT WHERE @EPID = EmpPT.EPID
RETURN @ret;
END
GO
```

Further reading here:

- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Got this: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.

Comment: You are right, forgot they needed to be slapped into a function. I edited my answer to show how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a combined table for all employees. The FT and PT tables could use foreign keys to the employee table.

Comment: This does not prevent same EPID being inserted into both FT & PT.

Comment: You could put a full-time Boolean field on the employee table, and insert triggers on the ft and pt tables preventing an insert from succeeding on the ft table where `employee.fulltime` is false or on pt where `employee.fulltime` is true. There may be a more elegant mechanism then triggers to accomplish this, but I am more used to approaching such issues through a front end then in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have primary keys span tables.  So, one method is to create a table `employee` with the appropriate constraints.  This might look like this:

```
create table employee (
    EPID int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    FTID int references empft(empftid),
    PTID int references emppt(empptid),
    CHECK (FTID is not null and PTID is null or FTID is null and PTID is not null),
    UNIQUE (FTID),
    UNIQUE (PTID)
    . . .
);

create table empft (
    EmpFTId int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);

create table emppt (
    EmpPTId int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    . . .
);
```

Of course, you could also use triggers if you wanted to.